# Cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'QLabel *'?

Tags: c++, qt, casting, stack-overflow

So, I am trying to use the following code to pass an object to a function in Qt, then convert it to a QLabel for further processing (it's part of an animation sequence):

```
    void myAnimation(QObject* label)
{
    QLabel *lbl = qobject_cast<QLabel*>label;

//more code.....
}
```

Yet, whenever I try to compile, I get the following two errors:

error: C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'QLabel *'
Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function

and

error: C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'label'

Why isn't my code working? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you missing a set of parenthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
QLabel *lbl = qobject_cast<QLabel*>(label);
//                                 ^     ^
```